# Iframe responsive height and width fit to content

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I've build an iframe that embed an html like the following:

```
<div class="document">                            
  <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/doc625.htm">
 </iframe>
</div>
```

While these are the classes that I've apply to the div and the iframe:

```
.document {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.document iframe {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;

}
```

The problem is that when I try to expand the screen, the height of the Iframe doesn't fit to their content.

How can I fix it?

These are the screenshots:

100% zoom

[image]

50% zoom

[image]

Comment: What is the address of the site you are framing? And maybe a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: So, I guess not, eh?

Comment: It is not online. I've upload 2 screenshots. As you see with zoom 100% is it ok but if I try to zoom out the iframe doesn't fit to their content.

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll` or `auto` on `.document` or you can try `body` as well but you should assign `position: relative` too.

Comment: It doesn't run with both 2 :( Only add other scroll bar. I've think to use @media and set the height in pixel when the screen change, but I think is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Are both pages in the same folder? I uploaded a demo btw.

Comment: Anyways I have successfully wrote a script that'll find the height of an iframe's content and adjust the iframe accordingly. Unfortunately Same Origin Policy applies. I plan to extend it's use for cross-domain functionality when I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uploaded 2 pages one child (page2.html) the other [parent (page1.html)](https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/page1.html).

I added defaults I use frequently, but the major changes are as follows:

```
.document {
      overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .document iframe {
      bottom: 0; right: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I found that the problem is in the section tag that I've before the div tag. Now I hope to find a solution.

Comment: Found:) I've change the div tag of bootstrap that I've before. <div class="container"> to <div class="container-fluid">

Comment: ahah :) Now I've other problem with the footer. After it I've a blank space. What do you think can I do?

Comment: Sorry is a stupid problem. I've lost to put bottom:0 lol :) :)

Comment: I was just about to say that. :D

Answer (score 0):

You mean the height of the iframe doesn't follow ?
I think you shouldn't use all these properties, just set your iframe dimensions with viewport sizes, like "vh" for the height and "vw" for the width, and set it to "100vh" and "100vw" like :

```
iframe {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't run. What's I mean is to enlarge and adapt to the content example when I have a screen more large and fit the height and the width.